# add a button to UITableViewCell that

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints, subview, uiswitch

I'm building table view for my setting. Since they have default layout I'm using the UITableViewCellStyles. In a few rows I need a switch.

In the code below the switch is 'jumping around' over my complete table view although a added the switch to the cell !!

How do I add a switch to cell that has a default style?

PS: I know how to do this using custom cells but I don't want to build them if it is not needed.

```
let mySwitch: UISwitch = {
    let assign = UISwitch()
    assign.setOn(true, animated: true)
    assign.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ContactDetailsVC.assignSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
    return assign
}()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // case .....

    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId")

    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Test"
    cell?.contentView.addSubview(mySwitch)
    cell?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]-20-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": mySwitch]))
    cell?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": mySwitch]))

    return cell!

    // case .....

}
```

Comment: If you want to custom your cell (with a switch button for example) you should not use a default style cell then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try it with accessoryView.

```
let mySwitch: UISwitch = {
let assign = UISwitch()
assign.setOn(true, animated: true)
assign.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ContactDetailsVC.assignSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
return assign
}()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// case .....

var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId")

cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")
cell?.textLabel?.text = "Test"
cell?.accessoryView = mySwitch
return cell!


}
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623219-accessoryview

Comment: add switch in UIView and that view assign to  accessoryView

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for putting me in the right direction (cell?.accessoryView). The let mySwith was also not working so I changed the code to:

```
var mySwitch = UISwitch()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   // case .....

   var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId")
   cell?.accessoryView = mySwitch
   mySwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
   mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SettingsVC.mySwitched), for: .valueChanged)

   // case
```